# How to use database that is on FTP server without downloading it?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ftp

I want to use SQLite database which is on FTP server without downloading it. Is it possible to use this database directly?

Comment: no - it is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the FTP protocol is designed to sequentially transfer the entire contents of files. There is no way to perform random reads/writes to a file, which is necessary for SQLite (or any database program) to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not now how SQLite works, but if you have your database-files on the server, you can mount the the filesystem over ftp and run a local SQLite-server which talks to the mounted files.

According to how the ftp-protocol is designed; If your database is just one file, the system will download the hole file even if you just want the first row, each time the file are needed(if we not use file-cache). If your database is multiple files each file will be downloaded when they are needed. As Pavel Krymets said, it will be slow, so it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite) for data providers used by SQLite only supports UNC paths, URL parameters are not supported. You must download the file locally.